# make user persistent on docker

Tags: server, ssh, docker

Is there any way to user created in a container when i recreate a container?
I'm using Ubuntu image to create a container to ssh into to modify a few file.
I don't wan't to use the root user to ssh so i'm creating a user to ssh with and it's working but if i recreate the container, my user needs to be recreated.

I'm using compose to builld the conaitner

```
ssh:
      image: ubuntu:latest
      container_name: school_ssh
      tty: true
      restart: unless-stopped
      volumes:
        - "./web:/home/websandbx"
        - "./ssh-conf:/etc/ssh"
      ports:
       - "2200:22"
```

I haven't seen any info on that subject,
I'm pretty sure I only need to keep the file that are used to configure the user, it's password and it's goup in volumes but I'm not sure which one...

If anyone could point me to the right direction that would be apppreciated